# how to insert data into database with column name from input user

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, jbossfuse

can I insert data into database with column name from input user ?

example:

```
INSERT INTO res_booking_status
(AirlineCode,
flightnumber,
departuredate,
totalbooking,:#${header[Subclass]}) 
       Values (:#${header[AirlineCode]},
       :#${header[FlightNumber]},
       :#$ { header[departuredate] },
1,
1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *JBoss Fuse*, but - as far as Oracle is concerned - you'd use dynamic SQL for such a purpose.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema - I'm inserting a row into the EMP table, into its EMPNO and ENAME columns (which are obligatory). The 3rd and 4th parameters of my procedure are

- custom column name
- custom value for that column

This is the EMP table:

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
```

A procedure:

- PAR_EMPNO and PAR_ENAME are obligatory columns' values
- PAR_COL1 is custom column name
- PAR_VAL1 is custom column's value
- L_STR variable contains SQL statement
- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE *runs* dynamic SQL, using parameters you passed:

.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_userins (par_empno   IN NUMBER,
  2                                         par_ename   IN VARCHAR2,
  3                                         par_col1    IN VARCHAR2,
  4                                         par_val1    IN VARCHAR2)
  5  IS
  6     l_str   VARCHAR2 (500);
  7  BEGIN
  8     l_str :=
  9           'insert into emp (empno, ename, '
 10        || par_col1
 11        || ') values (:a, :b, :c)';
 12
 13     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str USING par_empno, par_ename, par_val1;
 14  END;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC p_userins(1, 'LF', 'deptno', 20);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT empno, ename, job, sal, deptno FROM emp WHERE empno = 1;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
         1 LF                                      20

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

Now, how will you use it JBoss Fuse, no idea - if you can call a stored procedure, fine - above is the code you might want to adjust.

Comment: Although it would work fine for number and varchar2, additional code may be required to handle  date/timestamp column types

Comment: Absolutely, @Kaushik. This is just the simplest case.